# Unique rows in r with constraints to columns

Tags: r

I have looked at some of the examples here using the duplicated function. However, it doesn't seem to work for my problem.

Here is an example, where one might get a random number matrix of 2 cols.

```
set.seed(56)
a <- cbind(sample(1:6,10,replace=TRUE),sample(1:5,10,replace=TRUE)) 
b <- a[order(a[,1]),]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    4    3
[3,]    4    2
[4,]    5    4
[5,]    5    1
[6,]    6    5
[7,]    6    4
```

I want the first col to be unique. But also, I want the second col to be a value less than the adjacent value in the first col.

i.e. The result will look like.

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    4    3
[3,]    5    4
[4,]    6    5
```

The values in the first column are always changing, but the 2nd column must always be one less than the value on the first column.

Answer (score 1):

First get rows where column 2 is 1 less than column 1:

```
result = a[a[, 2] == a[, 1] - 1, ]
```

Then de-duplicate:

```
result = result[!duplicated(result[, 1]), ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Gregor, but the result becomes a single vector.

Comment: Thanks Gregor, that worked really well. I will bear in mind to make a reproducible example. Nevertheless, I edited the question so that people can produce a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You can first `split` by unique values in first column and then extract the first row from each sub-group that meets your requirement.

```
b = as.data.frame(b)
t(sapply(split(b, b$V1), function(x) x[which(x[,2] < x[,1])[1],]))
```